# SSL certificate locations when using an Xampp localhost setup

Tags: apache, ssl, localhost

Background: Windows Version: Windows 10 Pro Version 1909, OS build 18363.1082 with a Wordpress website (copied from a running on-line site) running on an Xampp/Apache localhost environment for development purposes.

I am trying to implement a secure localhost environment (because I copy my secure online website to my localhost environment) and it works fine in non-secure mode (HTTP://) but does not work in secure mode (HTTPS://). I get the deadly "your connection isn't private" message using HTTPS:// on Edge. To get rid of this message I have created a self signed Certificate Authority and added it to the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities store in Windows. I also created a Private Key (localhost.Key) and issued a new local certificate (localhost.crt) using the Root SSL certificate I created but I am not sure where localhost.key and localhost.crt go in the localhost configuration. Do I add them to httpd-ssl.conf, openssl.cnf or somewhere else? This part of the process does not appear to be covered on the internet sites I have looked at (and there was a lot of them). Actually I am also at a bit of a miss as to how the SSL process works in a local host development environment and how it ties into a locally installed Wordpress website (with SSL plugin installed). A details flowchart showing which certificates are used at each stage of the flow and where they come from in a localhost environment would be appreciated.

Any help in finishing off this project would be appreciated.